# I'm getting "keychain error" with cordova login button when using ionic CLI

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, authentication

I'm developing an mobile app with ionic and I want to add a google sign in. Like I'm using firebase I've implemented the login button with cordova-plugin-googleplus. It worked at first but recently, after a clean state and re-add the platform for iOS, it stopped working throwing the "keychain error" message on the console.

In Android it works fine; right now, I've tried everything (disable and re-enable keychain sharing capability, clean all the environment and rebuild it, check the entire GoogleService-Info.plist, checked the reversed_client_id, ... I don't know what I'm missing).

Some additional info:

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 1.2.1-nightly-1867
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.4
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.2
ios-deploy version: 1.8.6 
ios-sim version: 5.0.11 
OS: Mac OS X Sierra
Node Version: v4.4.4
Xcode version: Xcode 8.1 Build version 8B62
```

Plugins installed:

```
cordova-plugin-calendar 4.5.5 "Calendar"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.4 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.3.0 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-fcm 1.1.5 "FCMPlugin"
cordova-plugin-googleplus 5.1.1 "Google SignIn"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.5.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 2.1.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-transport-security 0.1.2 "App Transport Security"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.0 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

The config.xml file (part of it):

```
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplus" spec="~5.1.1">
    <variable name="REVERSED_CLIENT_ID" value="XXXX-THIS_HAS_THE_CORRECT_ID-XXXXX"/>
  </plugin>
```

The error message on the console:

```
keychain error
```

Some error message from the system.log of the emulator:

```
securityd[16035]: found no keychain client entitlements. task=Xxxxx App[17178]/1#0 LF=0 procid=com.xxxx.xxxx cs_flags=0x22000201
```

The login function in the controller:

```
  $scope.loginGoogle = function(){
    $ionicLoading.show();
    LogService.log(TAG, 'webClientId : ' + 'XXXXX');
    var clienInfo = {};

    if(ionic.Platform.isAndroid())
    {
      clienInfo.webClientId = 'XXXXXXX';
    }

    window.plugins.googleplus.login(
      clienInfo,
      function (obj) {
        // alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
        
        LogService.log(TAG, 'googleplus.login result : ' + JSON.stringify(obj));
        LogService.log(TAG, 'obj.idToken : ' + obj.idToken);
        // obj.email          // 'eddyverbruggen@gmail.com'
        // obj.userId         // user id
        // obj.displayName    // 'Eddy Verbruggen'
        // obj.familyName     // 'Verbruggen'
        // obj.givenName      // 'Eddy'
        // obj.imageUrl       // 'http://link-to-my-profilepic.google.com'
        // obj.idToken        // idToken that can be exchanged to verify user identity.
        // obj.serverAuthCode // Auth code that can be exchanged for an access token and refresh token for offline access
        var token = obj.idToken;
        var userData = {
          displayName : obj.displayName,
          avatar : obj.imageUrl,
          currentSessionOn : 'google'
        };
        return AuthService.loginGoogle(token, userData).then(function (result) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess);
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            $state.go('app.tabs.events');
        }).catch(function(error){
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            $scope.message = error.message;
            $timeout(function() {
              $scope.message = null;
            }, 3000);
            $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginFailed);     
        });
      },
      function (msg) {
        LogService.logError(TAG, 'plugins.googleplus.login error: ' + msg);
        $ionicLoading.hide();
      });
  };
```

Comment: Launching the project from Xcode appears to solve the problem. The problem is still present using Ionic CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Launching the project from Xcode appears to solve the problem. The problem is still present using Ionic CLI.

[Issue reported in github](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/313)

Comment: I seem to have the reverse problem as the above. When I launch my project from ionic serve it works fine (but then I am not using the Cordova Plugin, but rather AngularFire2). But when I launch the project in Xcode, I get the keychain error