# Google/Firebase Authentication no displayName or photoURL for iOS

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, google-plus, firebase-authentication

I am using Ionic2 and [GooglePlus Authentication](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/google-plus/).

I can sign in and it creates a User with a `uid` in the `Firebase Authentication` list as expected.

When I do this:

```
        GooglePlus.login({
            'webClientId': webClientId,
            'offline': true
        }).then(googleData => {
```

Where the `webClientId` matches the `Client ID` in the `iOS Credential` below.

**Problem:**

However, for `iOS`, the `googleData` does contain an `emailAddress` and `uid`, but the `displayName` and `photoURL` are `null`.

**More Info:**

I do have an `iOS Credential` set up with the `Bundle ID` matching the `widget id` in the `config.xml`:

[image]

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.XXXXXXX" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>theWhoZoo</name>
```

And it also has the `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID` matching the `iOS URL scheme` above.

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplus" spec="~5.1.1">
    <variable name="REVERSED_CLIENT_ID" value="com.googleusercontent.apps.XXXXXX" />
</plugin>
```

I have also created a `Firebase App` for my Project that also has the matching `Bundle ID` (not sure if this has any effect):

[image]

Also, I am not sure if this makes any difference, but I add the the `CLIENT_ID` for `iOS` to the Google Firebase Authentication here:

[image]

**Question**

Are there any steps I am missing or doing something wrong to set this up for `iOS`?

Comment: Do I need to install Cocoa Pods?  I would prefer to keep my app as simple and lightweight as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should add the required scope for fetching profile data:

```
window.plugins.googleplus.login({
  'scopes': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
  // continue below...
```

See the official [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#handle_the_sign-in_flow_with_the_firebase_sdk) and the plugin [documentation](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus#login) for details.

The scope is described [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#oauth2v2).

Comment: THANK YOU!!!   You solved my problem. I was trying to fix this the whole weekend.

Comment: Strangest thing happend that I can't explain. I made the change as you suggested, then in `Xcode` built the project, and it was returning the `displayName` and `photoUrl`. So I thought it was fixed. However, I then did an `ionic build ios`, then built it again in `Xcode`, and now it doesn't return the `displayName` and `photoUrl`.

Comment: Please try doing a clean build. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197369/how-to-force-refresh-the-cached-source-files-upon-ionic-build-run).

Comment: Thanks, I tried `ionic platform remove ios` then `ionic platform add ios` and then `ionic build ios`. Then ran the project in Xcode, an got the following: `keychain error`

Comment: There seems to be some crap with Ionic. See [1](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/313) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40955012/im-getting-keychain-error-when-login).

Comment: I seem to have the reverse problem as the above. When I launch my project from `ionic serve` it works fine (but then I am not using the Cordova Plugin, but rather AngularFire2). But when I launch the project in `Xcode`, I get the `keychain error`.

Comment: Very strange, I had Facebook sign in working, but now it does not work either with an `undefined` error. I'm guessing when I removed the `iOS` platform and re added it, something that I need got deleted.

Comment: Fixed the keychain error by adding the capability: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689631/how-to-use-facebook-ios-sdk-on-ios-10/38799196#38799196

Comment: I am getting inconsistencies. It was working perfectly, then it suddenly stopped returning the `displayName` again. I tried `ionic platform remove ios` then `ionic platform add ios` and then `ionic build ios` again, but still no `displayName`.

Comment: I'm not sure how awful Ionic CLI is, but please verify if you're running from the latest source. Otherwise, it's another question, so please ask or get support somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

here is my code and this is working good with IOS.

**Code**

```
private nativeGoogleLogin(): Promise<firebase.User> {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me';
      await this.gPlus.login({
          'webClientId': 'XXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com',
          'offline': true,
          'scopes': SCOPES
        }).then(res => {
            const googleCredential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(res.idToken , res.access_token);
            this.afAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(googleCredential).then(odata => {
              resolve(odata);
            }).catch(err => {
              reject(err);
            });
        }).catch(err => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  }
```

**How to get displayName name**

```
async onGoogleLogin() {
    await this.goAuth.googleLogin().then(res => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(res));
      alert(res.providerData[0].displayName);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

> res.providerData[0].displayName
>
> Note : Uninstall you app in emulator and clean your build folder before using this
>   code.