# Do I need Cocoa Pods?

Tags: xcode, angular, ionic2, cocoapods, firebase-authentication

I am using `Ionic2` and `Xcode` to build an app for `iOS`.

**Question**

**Do I need to install [`Cocoa Pods`](https://cocoapods.org/)?**

I would like to keep my app as small and simple as possible, so don't want to install anything unnecessary. However, I am trying to get `Firebase Authentication` up and running, and the [following instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin) are using `Cocoa Pods`.

I have tried to get `iOS` `Firebase Authentication` working without `Cocoa Pods`, but it only partially works, i.e. it logs in and returns a user with a `uid` and `emailAddress`, but no `displayName` and `photoUrl`.

[Google/Firebase Authentication no displayName or photoURL for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736623/google-firebase-authentication-no-displayname-or-photourl-for-ios)

Comment: CocoaPods is not CocoaControls.

Comment: Please can you elaborate on your comment? I don't understand what you are implying. The Firebase documentation has an example of iOS Authentication using Cocoa Pods, so my question is related to that. https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup

Comment: Apologies, I copied a link from someones youtube channel. I will correct it.

Comment: If you want update plugin like Firebase easier , you should use CocoaPod. If you think you can do manually, it doesn't matter!

Comment: Do you know why when I do it manually, Firebase returns a user but with a null displayName and photoUrl?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736623/google-firebase-authentication-no-displayname-or-photourl-for-ios

Comment: I think your main confusion is about CocoaPods. CocoaPods doesn't add anything to your app itself, it's a dependency manager which fetches, updates, etc. specific versions of dependencies (such as firebase) for you (Firebase in turn *is* added to your app and enlarged the binary size of your app, etc.)

Comment: If you're worried about keeping your app small you should use Objective-C instead of Ionic2.

Comment: CocoaPod just help you update the Firebase SDK, it doesn't do anything in your code or the way you connect with server. Because when Firebase SDK update, you have to update manually and sometimes it will conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not follow the Firebase guide if you're using a JS-based framework such as Ionic. Instead, just use AngularFire2. If CocoaPods is required, Ionic will handle automatically for you.

Your authentication problem is probably caused by OAuth scopes. Will provide the answer on your original one.

Comment: thanks for the advise. I have been using AngularFire2, but it doesn't seem to work for Devices (iOS and Android), but only on Web Browsers. I would appreciate it if you could look at my original question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736623/google-firebase-authentication-no-displayname-or-photourl-for-ios